# Linux sh script throws "#!/bin/sh: not found"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, sh

i have a script

```
#!/bin/sh

# Automatically remove a torrent and delete its data after a specified period of
# time (in seconds).

TARGET=/var/www/transmission/completed
USER=name
PASS=pass
BIN="/usr/bin/transmission-remote"

# The default is 5 minutes (in seconds).
CUTOFF=`expr 100 \* 3`

##############################################
### You shouldn't need to edit below here. ###
##############################################

# Tokenise over newlines instead of spaces.
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS="
"

for ENTRY in `$BIN -n $USER:$PASS -l | grep 100%.*Done.*Finished`; do

    # Pull the ID out of the listing.
    ID=`echo $ENTRY | sed "s/^ *//g" | sed "s/ *100%.*//g"`

    # Determine the name of the downloaded file/folder.
    NAME=`$BIN -n $USER:$PASS -t $ID -f | head -1 |\
         sed "s/ ([0-9]\+ files)://g"`

    # If it's a folder, find the last modified file and its modification time.
    if [ -d "$TARGET/$NAME" ]; then
        LASTMODIFIED=0
        for FILE in `find $TARGET/$NAME`; do
             AGE=`stat "$FILE" -c%Y`
             if [ $AGE -gt $LASTMODIFIED ]; then
                 LASTMODIFIED=$AGE
             fi
        done

    # Otherwise, just get the modified time.
    else
        LASTMODIFIED=`stat "$TARGET/$NAME" -c%Y`
    fi

    TIME=`date +%s`
    DIFF=`expr $TIME - $LASTMODIFIED`

    # Remove the torrent if its older than the CUTOFF.
    if [ $DIFF -gt $CUTOFF ]; then
        date
        echo "Removing $NAME with ID:$ID"
        $BIN -n $USER:$PASS -t $ID --remove-and-delete
    fi

done

IFS=$OLDIFS
```

but when i try to run it i get this error: /root/transmission_r.sh: 1: /root/transmission_r.sh: #!/bin/sh: not found

Comment: ...so, what does `ls /bin/sh` give you?

Comment: it gives me: /bin/sh

Comment: Any funny characters on that first line then?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/V6V4OJw.png

Comment: Ahh, got it, file encoding was set to UTF-8, i set it to without BOM and it works now.

Comment: Also, line endings might fool you.

Answer (score 23):

Your script starts with:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

This is not a comment, but a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to tell your operating system to use `/bin/sh` to execute the script. But apparently Ubuntu cannot find it.

- If `ls /bin/sh` shows no result, then I guess that needs to be fixed. As a temporary solution, you might be lucky that your script also works with, for example, bash:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  ```
- If `/bin/sh` *does* exist (like it should), then somehow Ubuntu cannot interpret that first line. Dump it as hex:

  ```
  head -n 1 myscript.sh | hexdump -C

  00000000  ef bb bf 23 21 2f 62 69  6e 2f 73 68 0d 0a        |...#!/bin/sh..|
  ```

  And with the result:

  - Make sure line endings are using the Unix format, LF (`\n` or hexadecimal `0a`) instead of, for example, the Windows standard CRLF (`\r\n` or hexadecimal `0d0a` in the example above). On a Mac this would actually throw a different error:

    ```
    /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
    ```
  - Make sure file encodings do not mess up, such as an (invisible) Unicode [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (`ef bb bf` in the example output above). In the above example your shell is not seeing a comment or the shebang, but is trying to run a command that starts with 3 invisible characters. In this case your shell would probably still execute the next lines, or might even complete the script successfully. On a Mac the first line actually throws:

    ```
    ./myscript.sh: line 1: #!/bin/sh: No such file or directory
    ```

To dump the error message to see the invisible characters in that message, one needs to redirect the error output to the standard output:

```
./myscript.sh 2>&1 | hexdump -C

00000000  2e 2f 6d 79 73 63 72 69  70 74 2e 73 68 3a 20 6c  |./myscript.sh: l|
00000010  69 6e 65 20 31 3a 20 ef  bb bf 23 21 2f 62 69 6e  |ine 1: ...#!/bin|
00000020  2f 73 68 3a 20 4e 6f 20  73 75 63 68 20 66 69 6c  |/sh: No such fil|
00000030  65 20 6f 72 20 64 69 72  65 63 74 6f 72 79 0a     |e or directory.|
```

Comment: transmission_r.sh: 1: transmission_r.sh: #!/bin/bash: not found

Comment: To remove it, open it in vi and do a ":setlocal nobomb"

Comment: it was CRLF endings in my case (with `/bin/sh: 1: script.sh: not found` error. wat).

Comment: Oh man! Line endings!!! That cost me hours, thanks for pointing out!