# I can't get echo output from the shell code

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting

I am more new to shell programming and I am encountering such an error. Why does it give such an error?
can you please tell me?

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo ""
    echo -e "       _      _   _ _  _   _"
    echo -e "__   _/ |_ __| |_| | || | | |__"
    echo -e "\ \ / / | '__| __| | || |_| '_ \"
    echo -e " \ V /| | |  | |_| |__   _| |_) |"
    echo -e "  \_/ |_|_|   \__|_|  |_| |_.__/"
    echo ""
```

**NOTE** : command I run -> `bash virtlab`

**ERROR**

```
virt_lab: line 1: #!/bin/bash: No such file or directory

       _      _   _ _  _   _
__   _/ |_ __| |_| | || | | |__
virt_lab: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
virt_lab: line 13: `echo -e "\ \ V /| | |  | |_\| |__   _\| |_) |"'
```

Comment: The backslash before the quote at the end of line 5 is the problem. A simple fix is to change `\"` to `\\"`.

Comment: thank you very much, my problem has been solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Main issue

This fragment:

> ```
> echo -e "\ \ / / | '__| __| | || |_| '_ \"
> echo -e " \ V /| | |  | |_| |__   _| |_) |"
> ```

These are *not* two separate commands. If you try to run just the first line, you will see the shell expects further input.

Double-quoted `\"` at the very end of of the first line is an escaped double-quote. It does not close the quoting. The following newline character is double-quoted, so the command continues. The quoting ends at the unescaped `"` after `echo -e` in the next line. The characters that follow are unquoted; this includes `| | |`. Unquoted `|` is a [pipe operator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/108618). Two or more pipe operators in a row are invalid, hence the error.

Since double-quoted backslash (`\`) can be special, it's safer to use single-quoted strings. Unless a string contains the single-quote character itself (`'`). Some of the strings in your code do, including the troublesome one. You can still achieve the desired result by quoting different parts differently, or by proper escaping.

Note by using `echo -e` (instead of plain `echo`) you made backslash [potentially special to `echo` as well](https://superuser.com/q/1249828/432690) (this fact didn't bite you though; yet). In general [it's better to use `printf`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618).

This is the troublesome command fixed in two different ways:

```
echo "\ \ / / | '__| __| | || |_| '_ \\"
echo "\ \ / / | '__| __| | || |_| '_ "'\'
```

There are more ways to properly quote/escape this entire string. In general you need to know how the shell interprets quotes, backslashes and such.

In this case, however, your code will be much more readable if you use [here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents).

```
cat <<'EOF'

       _      _   _ _  _   _
__   _/ |_ __| |_| | || | | |__
\ \ / / | '__| __| | || |_| '_ \
 \ V /| | |  | |_| |__   _| |_) |
  \_/ |_|_|   \__|_|  |_| |_.__/
EOF
```

Note I quoted `EOF` after `<<`. Without this quoting, some characters (including `\`) would/could be special, not literal.

---

#### Meta note

Our site gave you a hint by coloring your code in the question itself, as soon as you posted it. The coloring scheme seems to change. This is the screenshot (in case something breaks in the future):

[image: screenshot]

---

#### Side issue

If the file is `virtlab` and you run it with `bash virtlab` then [you don't need the shebang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136547/108618) (`#!/bin/bash`). It seems [there is something](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27054/108618) [wrong with the shebang](https://superuser.com/a/948866/432690) anyway, you got `No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 0):

for example you can writ like that :
echo '$''FileCreateMode 0640' >> /etc/rsyslog.conf

the output :
$FileCreateMode 0640

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).